# Strange character in HTML/VB6 Control

Tags: html, vb6

What is this? I am unable to view the source from the HTML control I am using in VB6, any help identifying the following character would be greatly appreciated.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rY0qLa2.png]

Comment: It's identified by the displayed glyph itself... unicode character NULL: U+0000. Maybe you are extra-null-terminating a string.

Comment: Paste into Wordpad or Word, select or place cursor at end of character or number, press Alt + Shift + X and it will toggle hex/character. Alt + Shift + Ctrl + F12 Hex to Unicode. In case Alt + X is already taken for another use.
Alt + Shift + X Converts the Unicode character preceding the insertion point to the corresponding Unicode hexadecimal value.
Alt + X Converts the Unicode hexadecimal value preceding the insertion point to the corresponding Unicode character.

Comment: @miguel-svq: replace(vbNullChar, "") worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Noodles: The Control I am working with has focused related issues, so copying the  character would of been impossible (can't select text).